# How to remove unused column names from Bigquery Schema

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using Bigquery I was trying to remove nested schmea like below, but couldn't able to do so. Can anyone please let me know

**Table:**

```
FiledName          Type       Mode
 Person            RECORD   NULLABLE
 Person.Name       STRING   NULLABLE
 Person.Add        RECORD   NULLABLE
 Person.Add.line   STRING   NULLABLE
```

**Code:**

```
ALTER TABLE `<project_id.dataset.table_name` DROP COLUMN 'Person.Add'
```

I have to remove entire record.

**Expected output:**

```
FiledName          Type       Mode
 Person            RECORD   NULLABLE
 Person.Name       STRING   NULLABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below approach - it selects all except of `person.add` and inserts into new table

```
create table `project_id.dataset.new_table_name` as 
select * replace(
    (select as struct person.* except(add)) as person
  )
from `project_id.dataset.table_name`;
```

Comment: small query. For the person fieldname what if i have "REPEATED" mode? How could i remove nested columns for that scenario? Could you please let me know?

Comment: I have voted and I will revert the question to original one. I will create a new one. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, It was undoubtedly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately per the documentation this cannot be done right now:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#details_14

The alternative would be to add a new Person record column with your desired fields, copy the data into it, then drop the old Person record.

Comment: Could you brief little bit how can achieve that? because i am not getting any data from that record. I don't want to copy anywhere. I just need to remove.